# How to use Lua FFI with C++ functions

Tags: ffi, torch, luajit

I have followed [this](https://github.com/Atcold/Torch-Developer-Guide/blob/master/FFI-so/README.md) tutorial to create an FFI interface to some C code to torch

However, it doesn't work for C++ functions. Is it even possible, if so how?

I created a shared library from the C++ file (simple.cpp) like so:

```
g++ -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libsimple.so simple.cpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ functions need to have C linkage to be used via FFI. Wrap the function signatures with extern "C" calls. More details here: [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)